# "email-inline.css" not loading file in magento for custom email

Tags: email, magento

I'm sending email from magento custom module of admin side. email is working,

but file `email-inline.css` not loading.....

when i use custom module of front side, it will send perfect email, also includes `email-inline.css` file, but didn't work from admin side ...

```
<!--@subject ActiveCodeline custom email module @-->
{{template config_path="design/email/header"}}
{{inlinecss file="email-inline.css"}}

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
 <tr>
    <td>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td class="action-content">
                    <h1>{{var title}},</h1>
                    <p>Your order <span class="no-link"># {{var mcode}}-{{var order.increment_id}}</span> has been declined from: <strong>{{var store_front_name}}</strong></p>

                    <p>Please review the reason for invoice declined.</p>
                     <h1>Reason</h1>
                    <p>{{var comment}}</p>  
                    <p>
                        If you have any questions, please feel free to contact us at
                        <a href="mailto:{{var store_email}}">{{var store_email}}</a>
                        {{depend store_phone}} or by phone at <a href="tel:{{var phone}}">{{var store_phone}}</a>{{/depend}}.
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

 {{template config_path="design/email/footer"}}
```

Answer (score 5):

You probably solved this by now, but I ran into a similar issue, when trying to send a custom email from a cronjob. Here is what I had to do :

```
// Set store
$previousStore = Mage::app()->getStore();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($_order->getStore()->getCode());
Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend');

/* Your email sending code */

// Restore config
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($previousStore->getCode());
```

The key part here is the `setArea('frontend')` which allows Magento to find your package/theme, where your CSS usually sits.

Hope this can help someone.